# Clean coding an HTML text-adventure game

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-organization

I'm building a text-based adventure game using HTML5, CSS and JavaScript but before I too far ahead of myself I was wondering how I should go about organizing my files. I was thinking rather than having one long HTML document would it be better to have multiple .js files for events and objects while linking everything through functions?

I got the idea from the way inform7 (an interactive text game builder) handles multiple scripts. Sadly i7 doesn't offer a way to play via web browser and demands downloading an interpreter program like Gluxle. Other if builders like Twine2 and Quest are nice but they seem very limited.

So far the title screen is done and I was just about to start making content for the game.

```js
// JavaScript Document

// Titlescreen
function fadeOutEffect() {
    var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("titlescreen");
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
        if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
        }
        if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        }
    }, 150);
}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
// Gamescreen

// L.Window

// M.Window

// R.Window
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color: #666;
    font-family: Roboto Mono;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    margin-top:20px;
}

/* Title Screen CSS */
.gamescreen {
    background-color:#333;
    margin:auto;
    padding:20px;
    width:864px;
    height: 504px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000000;
}

.version {
    font-size: 8px;
    text-align: right;
}

.gametitle {
    font-family: Fondamento;
    font-size:40px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF;
    animation: pulse 3s linear;
}

/*All titlescreen button animations*/
#start {
    animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
    background-color: #333;
    border: none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.start.game {
  display:none;
}

/* Add Later
#new {
    animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
    background-color: #333;
    border: none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}

#load {
    animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
    background-color: #333;
    border: none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}

#quit {
    animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
    background-color: #333;
    border: none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}
*/

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {opacity:0.1;}
    100% {opacity:1; text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF;}
}

/*In-Game Screen*/

.gamescreen {
    
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Path of Mice (Test)</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  
<link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fondamento&family=Roboto+Mono">
  
<script src="script.js"></script>

<!--jQuery Script Link
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
-->

</head>

<body>

<!--Title Screen-->
<div class="gamescreen">
<div id="titlescreen">
<p class="version">version 0.1.0 [Demo]</p>
<h1 class="gametitle">Path of Mice<br /></h1>
<img src="images/Warrior.png" alt="[Splash Art]" style="width:432px;height:288px;"><br />

<!--Start Button-->
<button id="start" onclick="fadeOutEffect()">[Begin]</button>


<!-- To Add Later
  <div id="menu">
    <button id="new" onclick="newGame()">New Game</button>
    <button id="new" onclick="loadGame()">Load Game</button>
    <button id="load" onclick="quitGame()">Quit Game</button>
  </div>
  -->
  
<!--Credits-->
  <p style="font-size:8px;">
    Path of Mice is an Interactive Fiction<br /><br />
    by Daryl Gray<br /><br />
    &#169; 2020 DTGray Arts</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Look at https://yeoman.io/ - for scaffolding your app.

Comment: On modern browsers you can create as many js files as you'd like to, and import them as modules. If you're more adventurous, you can take a look at parcel bundler (easier than webpack to start off with) which would bundle all js code into a single js file.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that.